# C# EWS - identification for SENT emails - InternetMessageId

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Im developing a Tickets System. 
I need to send a Ticket(mail) to a EmailAddressList and receive the answers by email regarding to this Email/Ticket.
Is there anyway to get an InternetMessageId from the new Ticket/Email that I sent?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that when you send your messages that you use `SendAndSaveCopy()` to place a copy of the message in the SentItems folder. Then you will want to use the `FindItems()` method to look for messages in the `WellKnownFolderName.SentItems`, instantiate an `EmailMessage` object and then you can look at the `InternetMessageId` property. Here is a brief example:

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId);
FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, view);
foreach (Item item in results)
{
    if (item is EmailMessage)
    {
        EmailMessage msg = item as EmailMessage;
        Console.WriteLine(msg.InternetMessageId);
    }
}
```

Here are a couple of links that may help you further:

[How to: Send email messages by using EWS in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600292%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)

[EmailMessage members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.emailmessage_members%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't want to hijack this answer, but I've used your answer here and applied it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24371952/138228 Do you think that's the best approach?