# Get id from just sended email

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I try to get the ID of email that I just send it through `Java EWS API`.
My goal is when I got that ID I would store it to Database.

This what I'm trying:

```
    try {
        String isiEmail     = generateIsiEmail(nmBank, jenis, tglAw, tglAk, produk);
        EmailMessage mail   = new EmailMessage(service);
        mail.setSubject(jdlEmail);
        mail.setBody(new MessageBody(isiEmail));

        //set to cc 
        mail.getToRecipients().add(new EmailAddress(from.replaceAll("\\s", "")));                   
        String[] too = to.split("\\;");
        for (int i = 0; i <too.length; i++) { 
            mail.getToRecipients().add(new EmailAddress(too[i].replaceAll("\\s", "")));                 
        }           
        String[] ccc = cc.split("\\;");
        for (int i = 0; i <ccc.length; i++) {
            mail.getCcRecipients().add(new EmailAddress(ccc[i].replaceAll("\\s", "")));
        }           
        mail.sendAndSaveCopy();
    } catch (ServiceLocalException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved by my self.
this step what I'm done with.
I use ExtendedPropertyDefinition refer from this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633654(v%3dexchg.80) , but I modified from C# into java programing language,

1. set ExtendedPropertyDefinition then save the uuidToStr to database

   ```
       UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
       ExtendedPropertyDefinition epd = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(uuid, "NamaId", MapiPropertyType.String);
       String uuidToStr = uuid.toString();

       String isiEmail     = generateIsiEmail(nmBank, jenis, tglAw, tglAk, produk);
       EmailMessage mail   = new EmailMessage(service);
       mail.setSubject(jdlEmail);
       mail.setBody(new MessageBody(isiEmail)); 

       //set to cc 
       mail.getToRecipients().add(new EmailAddress(from.replaceAll("\\s", "")));                   
       String[] too = to.split("\\;");
       for (int i = 0; i <too.length; i++){
           mail.getToRecipients().add(new EmailAddress(too[i].replaceAll("\\s", "")));                 
       }           
       String[] ccc = cc.split("\\;");
       for (int i = 0; i <ccc.length; i++){
           mail.getCcRecipients().add(new EmailAddress(ccc[i].replaceAll("\\s", "")));
       }           
       mail.setExtendedProperty(epd, "isiId"); 
       mail.sendAndSaveCopy();
   ```
2. get the email based on ExtendedPropertyDefinition uuidToStr from database

   ```
       UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("cc59cdbf-aad4-4cd1-a4f0-e7819c56b884");
       ExtendedPropertyDefinition epd = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(uuid, "NamaId", MapiPropertyType.String);

       ItemView view2 = new ItemView(3);
       SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(epd,"isiId");
       FindItemsResults<Item> fir = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, sf, view2);
       for (Item itm : fir.getItems()){
           System.out.println(itm.getId());
           System.out.println(itm.getSubject());  
       }
   ```

DONE;

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of the `InternetMessageId` property.

Call the `FindItems` method to search for messages in the sent items folder. Then instantiate an `EmailMessage` object so you can access the `InternetMessageId` property:

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(100); // You can change this to your needs.
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId);
FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, view);
foreach (Item item in results)
{
    if (item is EmailMessage)
    {
        EmailMessage emailMsg = item as EmailMessage;
        Console.WriteLine(emailMsg.InternetMessageId);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's right, your method is how to find email in send email folder and grab it's properties. I would use this if I cannot grab the ID from email that I just send it.
but my question, is posible to get the ID from email I just send it (after send and grab it's ID / grab after sended).

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm misunderstanding you but I'm pretty sure the answer I posted does what your looking for. When you call the `SendAndSaveCopy()` method, a copy of the email is saved into the sent items folder.

Comment: In EWS when you send a Message it asynchronous which is why the Id isn't returned in the Send Operations as it isn't available. So the answer above is the best way to go about it .

Comment: @MadDev yes, u'r answers is right, missed explaination about EWS run asynchronous like Glen Scales said.  Thanks Glen Scales and ManDev

Answer (score 1):

I am using `C# EWS Api`, But this logic will work for you.
First you have to **Save the email in Draft and then after you can get Email id**.

```
EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage(service);
emailMessage.From = email.From;
emailMessage.Subject = email.Subject;
emailMessage.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, email.Body);

foreach (var toAddress in email.To)
{
  emailMessage.ToRecipients.Add(toAddress);
}

// Send message and save copy by default to sentItems folder
emailMessage.Save();
emailMessage.Load();

// Get Email Conversation Id.
string ConversationId = emailMessage.ConversationId.UniqueId;
string EmailMessageId;

emailMessage.SendAndSaveCopy();


// Get Email Message Id by InternetMessageId.
List<SearchFilter> searchFilterCollection = new List<SearchFilter>();
            searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId, InternetMessageId));

// Create the search filter.
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or, searchFilterCollection.ToArray());

ItemView view = new ItemView(50);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId);
            FindItemsResults<Item> results = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, searchFilter, view);

            
if (results.Items.Count > 0)
{
 Item item = results.Items[0];
 EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id);

 EmailMessageId = message.Id.UniqueId;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer. No need to write additional codes. Works out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the solution is this:

```
EmailMessage em = EmailMessage.bind( service, item.getId(),
                   new PropertySet( EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId) );
```

Explanation :

We have to bind the item to an email message, but instead of grabbing all the info, we only ask for the ID and any additional properties we want through the PropertySet parameter.

found -> [Exchange Web Services get Message Message-ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370998/exchange-web-services-get-message-message-id/24371952#24371952)

Comment: let me try first

Comment: I think your answer is how to get any additional properties from email when we know the ID. but my question is how i get the ID from email I just send it (after send and grab it's ID)