# Assigning and accessing custom email headers in .NET

Tags: email, exchangewebservices

I need to add a custom header to an email using the System.Net.Mail.MailMessage class and then using the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage class I need to read that value.

What I'm trying to do exactly is bounce processing for emails we send out. I am generating a new Guid value and adding it to the headers right before it's sent. I'm storing that value in a database and need to match it up when a separate process scans the inbox for processing. I all of that working except one part - I can't get the message ID from the header.

I know messages have a Message-ID header (which is automatically added) and I can access that but what I'm having difficulty with is getting that value when it's sent in the first place. Is that even possible? If so I'll use that instead of my own value.

I can get the email address and the other relevant information but the system I've written uses the message ID I was assigning as the foreign key used in joins in the database.

Any guidance on this would be appreciated. I doubt I'm the only person whose ever tried doing this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456187/c-sharp-ews-identification-for-sent-emails-internetmessageid/22482779#22482779

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, the email I was testing with didn't have the header in it, that's why it couldn't be found.

I created a new email with it added and I could access it through the InternetMessageHeaders property of the EmailMessage object.